# How to get the real width of an element in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, width, material-design-lite, dimension

Fellow Developers,

I'm having an with some controls, it's the following one, some of them are larger than the screen:

[image: larger]

However, if I get the width either with JS or jQuery, I get always the same value 300px.

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

And if you see carefully the first screen says: 406px, do you have any idea why cannot I get the proper value?

Here is the code that I showed above.

```
$($('.mdl-textfield__input')[0]).outerWidth()
$($('.mdl-textfield__input')[0]).width()
```

Also, you can access the website from here:

https://fanmixco.github.io/toastmasters-timer-material-design

Important detail, this is the iPhoneX view in Chrome.

Comment: Seems to me you are using CSS transform. Try something like $(".mdl-textfield__input")[0].getBoundingClientRect().width.

Comment: Perfect answer @Sagar! Please add it and I marked it as the right one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me you are using CSS transform. Try something like 
`$(".mdl-textfield__input")[0].getBoundingClientRect().width`